# how to parse values from comma separated values using regex for javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

I have

```
HOSTNAMEA,HOSTNAMEB,HOSTNAMEC,...
```

I have a third party workflow tool that can do the looping but can only use regex to parse values. I'd like to get a regex that grabs each hostname and puts into it's own variable in my workflow tool so the results will be

```
HOSTNAMEA
HOSTNAMEB
HOSTNAMEC
...
```

I'm struggling to get a regex that just grabs the text block X between the commas

Comment: Why not use `.split(',')` method. It would split the string on every occurrence of , and return an array with the tokens.

Answer (score 1):

ever heard of `\w+` if you just want the strings between the comma, you can use `.split(", ")` as well

```
var str = "HOSTNAMEA,HOSTNAMEB,HOSTNAMEC";
var res = str.match(/\w+/g);
console.log(res.join(" "));
```

sample code for your help

Comment: That's the best answer. You can even change it to `str.match(/\w+/g).sort();` for a sorted array.